# Сделать скриншот сайта не сохраняя картинку

Tags: php, javascript, screenshots

Суть такая. Есть сайт, где люди размещают рекламу своих сайтов. Код обрабатывает NodeJS и если все гуд, заносит в базу юрл и описание сайта. После, через пых я вытаскиваю значения с базы и подставляю в страницу для вывода. Вот хороший пример: http://snipcode.ru/catalog.html?snipid=24 но сохранять сам файл со скриншотом на сервере не желательно.

Можно ли как-то по ссылке вывести что-то типа скриншота ? js или php не важно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос снят...
На ночь что-ли, протупил сначало...

Скрин можно взять с самого хостинга в виде http://mini.s-shot.ru/1024x768/600/jpeg/?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/